# Web applications to use burp suite on

Tags: penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

I am new to web pentesting  and I want to know what web applications can I use burp suite on. As far as I know, A damn vulnerable web application is one of them. I don't want to get in any trouble by doing random tests.

Comment: prbly the best way is to run your own services locally in a vm or on a server you own

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of our testing and tutorials we use OWASP Broken Web Apps. This will give you a range of targets to get started on.

Answer (score 0):

To learn web penetration testing, there are a lot of ressources out there.

To make sure you don't intrude anywhere that you are not allowed to, stick to CTF platforms/sites.

Some examples are:

- [hacker101](https://www.hacker101.com/)
- [hackthebox](https://hackthebox.eu/)
- [picoCTF](https://picoctf.com/)
- [hacking lab](https://www.hacking-lab.com/index.html)
- [pwnable](https://pwnable.tw/)

There are many more like this out there!

In addition to that, you could also take a look at [Vulnhub](https://www.vulnhub.com/) where people upload VMs as challenges for penetration testers. 
If you are downloading and starting VMs from strangers, make sure to take some precautions (isolate them in a lab-network without access to your normal lan etc) to stay safe.

Not every CTF challenge will need BurpSuite though, but you'll quickly find out - if a scan for `TCP/80` and `TCP/443` turns up nothing, move on to the next. (Or dive in deeper, if you like)